# Run jQuery on second website by clicking the button in first website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I have one scenario that in first website I have a link and second website have some jQuery alert.

What I want is that by clicking the link in first website alert will show in second website without reloading any page. Both websites are open in different machines.

Language of websites: PHP

Comment: well you need to poll the server and do some sort of messaging.... tons of ways to do it. Either Ajax calls or websockets.

Comment: That is effectively a "chat" scenario. I'm sure there must be chat  tutorials/examples on the web. I would recommend doing a search and start learning/adapting from there.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

1. Long-polling: Basically, whenever your button is clicked, you change something in the server, e.g you change a column in your database. And all the while, in your second page (the one you want to make the alert), you have a long-lived connection to another server-side file that constantly checks the value of that column in the database, and whenever you detect a change (which reflects the click), you return something to your JQuery (I implemented that using a `while` loop and the `sleep` function in PHP.
2. Websockets, in PHP, this means [Ratchet](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet).

For your case, I recommend the first approach, much simpler and easier to implement. I would use websockets for something like instant-messaging.